# Convert AppleScript to one line

Tags: random, applescript, text-files

I'm using Mach Desktop to echo a script's results into a Desklet, so it has to be in this format:

echo 'tell application "iTunes" to return album of current track' | osascript

I have a single line in which to enter data, so the script needs to be one long string.
It may be that the entire thing must be contained within one set of single quotes after echo, as follows:

echo '[entire script]' | osascript

How do I convert the AppleScript below to one line?

```
set some_file to "Macintosh HD:Users:Zade:Library:Application Support:Notational Data:Words.txt" as alias
set the_text to read some_file as string
set the text item delimiters of AppleScript to ", "
set the_lines to (every text item of the_text)
return some item of the_lines
```

Here is what I'm trying:

```
echo 'set some_file to "Macintosh HD:Users:Zade:Library:Application Support:Notational Data:Words.txt" as alias -e set the_text to read some_file as string -e set the text item delimiters of AppleScript to ", " -e set the_lines to (every text item of the_text) -e return some item of the_lines' | osascript
```

And that gives this error:

107:112: syntax error: A "set" can't go after this identifier. (-2740)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know where to start, especially since it's all on one line. I thought this would be super simple for you guys.

Comment: @Zade You're right, this is easy, but you're just making it more complicated than it needs to be. See my edit for more info. :)

Comment: @Zade I meant encompass each **individual** line, not the whole thing. Also, to which `set` does the error point? I haven't used Mach Desktop but from what I know about using `osascript`, the lines are delimited by `-e` and encompassed in single quotation marks.

Comment: Never mind, I figured out I could just refer to the script with "osascript /Users/Zade/Library/Scripts/Words.scpt". You rock fireshadow!

Comment: Now I have a new question that I bet you could answer in ten seconds: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8829824/applescript-trim-spaces-and-return-line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you could try out this script. I'm confused as to what you're actually trying to accomplish, though, so I apologize if this script is unsatisfactory.

```
echo 'set some_file to "~/Library/Application Support/Notational Data/Words.txt" as POSIX file as alias' -e 'set the_text to read some_file' -e 'set the text item delimeters of AppleScript to ","' -e 'set the lines to (every text item of the_text)' -e 'return the lines' | osascript
```

**EDIT:** @Zade That would be because `Words.txt` doesn't exist. Aliases only refer to existing files. Therefore, you must choose a file that exists. Here is an easy way to see what the correct syntax is for file references:

```
set some_file to (choose file)
```

You will notice that the file path is delimited by colons ( : ) rather than slashes. Having said this, choose a file that exists, and run your script with that file.

Comment: Thank you. See my updated description. I have tried to be as clear as possible, so please tell me if anything is still confusing. The line you wrote gives me the following error: 99:104: syntax error: A "set" can't go after this identifier. (-2740)

Comment: @Zade Does it say which "set" is causing the error? Also, try running the script from AppleScript editor. Replace all the -e's with newlines, and take out all the single quotation marks. Then, try running it

Comment: In AppleScript it says "can't make file Words.txt into type alias." If I take out "as alias" it says "can't make file into type file." Same error if I also take out "as POSIX file". See script now added to question.

Comment: Okay we're getting somewhere. I had to take the POSIX part out for it to even find the file. See updated description. But now I'm getting the error "Can't set every line to {"entry 1", "entry 2", "entry 3"}. And I don't think this script will return a random entry as it is now, seems like it's returning the whole thing.

Comment: @Zade I am so sorry I misunderstood. Change `return the lines` to `return some item of the lines`. Also, you might want to append the coercion `as string` to the line `set the_text to read some_file`

Comment: Thanks! Okay I got it working by fixing "the lines" to "the_lines". But now how do I put it onto one line?

Comment: @Zade Encompass all of the lines in single quotation marks and insert `-e` in between each line

Comment: See the updated description (sorry for changing it so much). It's giving me that error. I wonder if there's another way to do this that Mach Desktop likes.