# Applescript: trim spaces and return line

Tags: random, applescript, text-files

I wrote an AppleScript that returns a random string from a text file delineated by commas:

```
set some_file to "Macintosh HD:Users:Zade:Library:Application Support:Notational Data:Words.txt" as alias
set the_text to read some_file as string
set the text item delimiters of AppleScript to ", "
set the_lines to (every text item of the_text)
return some item of the_lines
```

But I now have a text file delineated by new lines instead of commas. And each line begins with anywhere from 0-20 spaces. I want to return just the text portion of a random line. How do I do this?

Also, if the text portion is surrounded by plain (not curly) quotes, how can I trim the quotes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following script will handle the additional requirements from your comments, and includes statements to trim characters from the beginning and ending of the string.  It excludes the first 27 lines read from the file and will repeatedly get and trim random lines from the list until the final result is not empty.

```
set theFile to (choose file)
set theLines to paragraphs 28 thru -1 of (read theFile)

repeat -- forever

    set someLine to some item of theLines

    -- trim characters at the start
    if someLine is not "" then repeat until the first character of someLine is not in {space, tab, quote}
        if (count someLine) is 1 then
            set someLine to ""
            exit repeat
        end if
        set someLine to text 2 thru -1 of someLine
    end repeat

    -- trim characters at the end
    if someLine is not "" then repeat until the last character of someLine is not in {quote}
        if (count someLine) is 1 then
            set someLine to ""
            exit repeat
        end if
        set someLine to text 1 thru -2 of someLine
    end repeat

    if someLine is not "" then exit repeat
end repeat

return someLine
```

Comment: This is awesome, thank you. Every once in awhile it's returning strange symbols if there are non-standard characters like curly quotes in my text file. Is there an easy way to filter/fix these?

Comment: If the characters are on the ends where you are already trimming, you can just copy the characters and add them to the list(s), otherwise something like a shell script that strips out all undesired characters may be the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I use to trim spaces from both ends of a string

```
 on trimWhiteSpace(aString)
    if aString is not "" then
        -- setup for no delimiter
        set savedTextItemDelimiters to AppleScript's text item delimiters
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
        -- start with the tail end by revering the list
        set these_items to reverse of (every text item of aString)
        -- keep peeling off 1st space
        repeat while item 1 of these_items is space
            set these_items to rest of these_items
        end repeat
        -- flip the list, now do the leading characters
        set these_items to reverse of these_items
        repeat while item 1 of these_items is space
            set these_items to rest of these_items
        end repeat
        -- reconstruct the string
        set these_items to these_items as string
        -- restore and return
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to savedTextItemDelimiters
        return these_items
    end if
end trimWhiteSpace
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the comma and space in the line `set the text item delimiters of AppleScript to ", "` to `return`. The new line (no pun intended) looks like this:

```
set the text item delimiters of AppleScript to return
```

As for your second question try this:

```
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
return text items 2 thru -2 of some_string
```

Let's put it all together!

```
set some_file to "Macintosh HD:Users:Zade:Library:Application Support:Notational Data:Words.txt" as alias
set the_text to read some_file as string
set the_lines to (every paragraph of the_text)
set this_line to some item of the_lines
if this_line is not "" then
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
    set this_line to (text items 2 thru -2 of this_line) --remove the quotes
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to space
    set these_items to (every text item of this_code)
    set the this_line to (item 1 of these_items & this_line)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
    return this_line
end if
```

**EDIT:** You can't stop the program from returning empty lines, but you can filter them out like so...

```
if paragraph i of some_text is not "" then do_something()
```

Comment: You can also trim the first character from the string, repeating until the first character is not a space (or whatever).

Comment: @fireshadow52 using "return" didn't work but I just set the_lines to (every paragraph). Now how can I exclude the first 27 lines of the text file from this operation?

Comment: Furthermore, how do I exclude returning empty lines and instead just return another line that has text?